Random Webpages Opening on Samsung Phone after Google App Opened
Whenever my Dad opens the Google app after his Samsung phone being off, a random website opens in Chrome through a floating window.
I have two separate text files taken right after from the "dumpsys activity activities" command, but I can't seem  to find what app is actually opening it.
What would I need to look for in the files and is there anything else I can do to try and find the bad app? If anyone wants, I could upload the files somewhere and attach them here.
I have attached the output through Google Docs if anyone wants to look at it.

You could include the contents of one of the files.  Or at least the beginning portion

There are a few suggestions.

Install and run ADB to look into it
Uninstall 5 or 10 apps at a  time, reboot and test. Once you have the nasty batch, check one at a  time. I am sure he wont have more than 50 odd apps, it wont take that long.
Change the default browser.  If it still opens Chrome, then it is likely to be a system app

